# mySQL bind_param with IN(?)

Tags: php, mysqli

Using `bind_param` on all my queries, I now want to use an `IN(?)` where the number of elements in the list can vary.

The SQLout function I'm using here basically does a `$sql_db->prepare`, `->bind_param`, `->execute()`, `->store_result()`, `->bind_result`

```
// the code below does not work as the query only matches on element 'a':
$locations = ('a','b','c','d','e');

SQLout ("SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE Locations IN (?)",
    array('s', $locations), array(&$usrName));


// the code below does work as a brute-force method,
// but is not a viable solution as I can't anticipate the number of elements in $locations going forward:

SQLout ("SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE Locations IN (?,?,?,?,?)",
    array('sssss', $locations[0],$locations[1],$locations[2],$locations[3],$locations[4]), array(&$usrName));
```

Has anyone come up with a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: PDO answers has nothing to do with mysqli problems. PDO is a heaven compared to mysqli in terms of handling variable number of prepared statements

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is one place placeholders fall on their faces. Minus the auto-escaping, they're almost literally just a string replacement operation internally, meaning that if you have `WHERE Locations IN (?)`, and pass in `1,2,3,4`, you'll get the equivalent of

```
WHERE Locations IN ('1,2,3,4')  // note, it's a string, not individual comma-separated integers
```

logically equivalent to

```
WHERE Locations = '1,2,3,4' // again, just a string
```

instead of the intended

```
WHERE Locations = 1 OR Locations = 2 OR Locations = 3 OR Locations = 4
```

The only practical solution is to build your own list of comma-separated placeholders (`?`), e.g:

```
$placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($values), '?'));
$sql = "SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE Locations IN ($placeholders)";
```

and then bind your parameters are usual.

Comment: `$stmt->execute($values)`. easy as can be.

Comment: Unfortunately, binding prepared statements in mysqli is not as easy as in PDO. Mysqli doesn't have `$stmt->execute($values)` feature. Nor it have bindValue method (so you can't bind in a loop using iterated variable) which makes such a simple task a circus and a nightmare at once. This is why this answer is way incomplete

Comment: Works best for my case. I'll have to run some speed tests on the use of long IN elements.

Comment: @MarcB Where you have used implode - why no comma separator? Are you deliberately forming a string like: "????????????" as opposed to "?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?"

Answer (score 2):

As Hazmat said, you need to build up the parameters and then pass them by calling `call_user_func_array` on the prepared statement, but slightly closer to working code than his example :)

```
//In the calling code
$queryString = "SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE Locations IN (";
$queryString .= getWhereIn($locations);
$queryString .= " )";

$parametersArray = array();

foreach($locations as $location){
    $parameter = array();
    $parameter[0] = 's'; //It's a string
    $parameter[1] = $location;

    $parametersArray[] = $parameter;
}



//This is a function in a class that wraps around the class mysqli_statement
function    bindParameterArray($parameterArray){

    $typesString = '';
    $parameterValuesArray = array();

    foreach($parameterArray as $parameterAndType){
        $typesString .= $parameterAndType[0];
        $parameterValuesArray[] = $parameterAndType[1];
    }

    $finalParamArray = array($typesString);
    $finalParamArray = array_merge($finalParamArray, $parametersArray);
    call_user_func_array(array($this->statement, "bind_param"), $finalParamArray);
}

function getWhereIn($inArray){
    $string = "";
    $separator = "";
    for($x=0 ; $x<count($inArray) ; $x++){
        $string .= $separator."?";
        $separator = ", ";
    }
    return  $string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can "build" in `IN` clause before you prepare/bind it.

```
$sql = 'SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE Locations IN (' . implode(array_fill(0, count($locations), '?')) . ')';
```

Then you can use `call_user_func_array` to bind the parameters, without ever knowing how many there are.

```
// Parameters for SQLOut
$params = array(
    # The SQL Query
    $sql,
    # The params for bind_param
    array(str_repeat('s', count($locations))),
    # The params for bind_result
    array(&$usrName)
);

// Add the locations into the parameter list
foreach($locations as &$loc){
    // not sure if this is needed, but bind_param
    // expects its parameters to be references
    $params[1][] = &$loc;
}

// Call your function
call_user_func_array('SQLout', $params);
```

<sub>Note: This is untested</sub>

Answer (score -1):

IN is usually slow and not prepared statement friendly.  The better solution is to build a table of the items that would be in the IN and use a JOIN to get the same effect.

Comment: @Your Then provide an example of how to get variable numbers of values in the IN.

Comment: @your please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771183/sql-fixed-value-in-vs-inner-join-performance The problem with IN is that you can't index the list like you can in a table and as the list gets longer the performance degrades quickly.  Of course it's fast when the list is short.

Answer (score -2):

> Has anyone come up with a more elegant solution to this?

Sure. I have.

Mysqli is practically unusable with prepared statements, especially with such complex cases.
So, it's better to get rid of prepared statements and implement your own placeholders with support of all **real life cases** that a developer can meet.

[safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) (a creation of mine) has a solution you're looking for (and also solutions for a dozen other headaches as well).

In your particular case, it would be as easy as this single line of code

```
// the code works alright:
$locations = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$usrName = $db->getCol("SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE Locations IN (?a)", $locations);
```

Unlike ugly codes you can get while playing with some PHP and API functions (and still get disturbing warnings depends on the PHP version you're using at the moment), this code is neat and **readable**. This is an important matter. You can tell what this code does even after a year has passed.

Comment: It's still going to be slow if the list is long http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771183/sql-fixed-value-in-vs-inner-join-performance

Comment: I've no idea where your repuation has come from on this website when you started this answer with "Mysqli is practically unusable with prepared statements".

Comment: @AFriend oh that's simple :). Just get back into 2013, try to use mysqli and you'd clearly see what I meant. Cheers.