# Query with WHERE / sub query containing multiple records

Tags: mysql

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM img_ref WHERE id_img = (SELECT `id_img` FROM img_ref WHERE `id_user`=4)
```

I'm trying to SELECT records from img_ref WHERE id_img = id_img attached to a specific id_user.

However, the subquery contains multiple rows/results and therefore throws the error "Subquery returns more than one row". How could I modify this statement so that the "WHERE id_img=" part and subquery allow multiple rows?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a subquery with equals, the subquery can only return a single record.  Normally you would just use `IN` to return multiple records:

```
SELECT * 
FROM img_ref 
WHERE id_img IN (SELECT `id_img` FROM img_ref WHERE `id_user`=4)
```

---

For performance reasons (check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771183/sql-fixed-value-in-vs-inner-join-performance)), you may want to move this to a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM img_ref i
    JOIN img_ref i2 ON i.id_img = i2.id_img 
        AND i2.id_user=4
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/187ae8/1)

Comment: The sub query is needed because id_img can be related to multiple id_user so I'm trying to check which other id_user's are in that table with the same id_img.

Comment: Is there any way to optimize this query better, IN seems to be very slow (1.5secs)? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user2980769 -- ok, that makes sense.  I'll remove that.

Comment: @user2980769 -- I edited the solution to include an alternative answer.  Best regards!