# Mysql SubQueries to join tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

My problem is as follows:

I have 3 tables with  content:

```
tableA:|ID_A|field1|field2|field3| => base table


tableB:|ID_B | ID_C |ID_A| => Mapping Table


tableC:|ID_C |FieldToGet| => Additional info field table
```

*** Important assumption: It is possible that there is multiple values of ID_C associated with the same ID_A
such that tableB: has the following structure:`

```
| ID_B | ID_C | ID_A|

|  24  |  81  |  23 |

|  25  |  11  |  23 |

|  26  | 82   |  23 |

|  27  | 42   |  24 |

|  28  | 113  | 33  |
```

but  if there is to be multiple ID_B for a single ID_A, they will follow each other.

Now, I am writing a php script to fetch the required fied for a certain ID_A, but it fails because my subquery returns multiple rows.:

```
$q = $this->dao->prepare('SELECT FieldToGet FROM table3  WHERE ID_C = ( SELECT ID_C FROM table2 WHERE ID_A =$SOME_ID_A )');
```

I am looking for either a solution that only fetches results from columm FieldToGet ( My current attempt) or a solution that will join the whole basetable, with the column FieldToGet ( unsure about how to use the JOIN opearation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the join will look like this,

```
SELECT  a.*, c.*   -- select the columns you want to get
FROM    tableA a
        INNER JOIN tableB b
            ON a.ID_A = b.ID_A
        INNER JOIN tableC c
            ON b.ID_C = c.ID_C
```

To fully gain knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: What if I want to filter out only for a single ID_A, instead of fetching all the results ? Also is it possible to extend this call to join another set of tables for instance tableD and tableE that are linked to tableA the same way tableB and tableC were, or do I have a separate query?

Comment: "*What if I want to filter out only for a single ID_A, instead of fetching all the results?*" -- just add `WHERE` clause condition in your query, example `SELECT...FROM...WHERE a.ID_A = 1` "*Also is it possible to extend this call to join another set of tables for instance tableD and tableE that are linked to tableA*" -- yes, just do the same for tableB and tableC and define their linking columns in `ON` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure I understand your needs.  @JW correctly shows you how to use the INNER JOIN to connect your 3 tables together.

Your query is very close.  Instead of using WHERE ID_C =, you should use WHERE ID_C IN ().

```
SELECT FieldToGet 
FROM table3  
WHERE ID_C IN (SELECT ID_C FROM table2 WHERE ID_A =$SOME_ID_A)
```

I personally prefer using JOINs over INs, but depending on your DB structure, using IN could actually perform better as using JOINs could return multiple results and require the use of DISTINCT or GROUP BY.  Here was a good post I read about it:

http://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/

And one on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4755644/1073631

Good luck.

Comment: Ok got it. JW answer was right on, but now i'd like to know if it's possible to extend the query to join 2 other tables to tableA, that have the same links to tableA  as tableB and tableC did. Do you follow me ?

Comment: Best bet would be to post a new question.  However, if I understand your question, assuming your 2 other tables have a field that can link to Table A (ID_A), you can easily join on as many as you need to.   From @JW's answer, SELECT  * FROM    tableA a INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.ID_A = b.ID_A INNER JOIN tableC c ON b.ID_C = c.ID_C INNER JOIN tableD d ON a.ID_A = d.ID_A etc etc.  Understood?  Again, depends on your desired results.  Good luck.